# Can I plot points on a map using JSON data from a Node.js API?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, node-js

I am new to the arcGIS JavaScript API.  I have a Node API that is providing geographical information in JSON.  I have google'd for examples and searched for solutions on this web site.  Can anyone point me towards an example where JSON data is used to plot points on a map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[this](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/fl_featureCollection.html) is the sample you should start by taking a look at.

in general, you need to use [esriRequest](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/esri.request-amd.html#esrirequest) to fetch your data, and then parse as appropriate before passing to a FeatureLayer or creating your own graphics and adding them to the map.

Comment: John thank you for the suggestion.  I will check it out.